# Running karma from teamcity. Chrome Testrunner fails to launch

Tags: angularjs, teamcity, karma-runner

We installed karma with the teamcity reporter on our build server. It was running unit tests through Chrome, Firefox, and IE and everything was working great. Then yesterday I noticed that Chrome was failing to report. IE and Firefox were still connecting and running all the unit tests but for some reason karma is not able to open a connection with Chrome so it times out after 60 seconds and the build step fails.

Whats really strange is that i can login to the build server and run this from the command line fine with no problems. The tests run (and they are very fast).

karma start --reporters teamcity --single-run --log-level error --browsers=IE,Firefox,Chrome

Here's the build log from teamcity. Does anyone have a clue what's going on? As you can see firefox and ie report fine but Chrome just falls on its face every time. I appreciate any help you might be able to offer.

```
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [config]:  [39mLoading config C:\TCBuildConf\01-OpSuiteDev\02-codebase\Website\OpSuite.MobileWeb\Client\unit_tests\karma.conf.js
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [config]:  [39mautoWatch set to false, because of singleRun
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [plugin]:  [39mLoading karma-* from C:\Users\administrator.OPSUITE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [plugin]:  [39mLoading plugin C:\Users\administrator.OPSUITE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher.
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [plugin]:  [39mLoading plugin C:\Users\administrator.OPSUITE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-firefox-launcher.
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [plugin]:  [39mLoading plugin C:\Users\administrator.OPSUITE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-ie-launcher.
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [plugin]:  [39mLoading plugin C:\Users\administrator.OPSUITE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-jasmine.
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [plugin]:  [39mLoading plugin C:\Users\administrator.OPSUITE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules/karma-teamcity-reporter.
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [32mINFO [karma]:  [39mKarma v0.12.16 server started at http://localhost:7357/
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [32mINFO [launcher]:  [39mStarting browser IE
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [temp-dir]:  [39mCreating temp dir at C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\karma-43795558
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [launcher]:  [39mC:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe -extoff http://localhost:7357/?id=43795558
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [32mINFO [launcher]:  [39mStarting browser Firefox
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [temp-dir]:  [39mCreating temp dir at C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\karma-44455821
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [launcher]:  [39mC:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe http://localhost:7357/?id=44455821 -profile C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\karma-44455821 -no-remote
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [32mINFO [launcher]:  [39mStarting browser Chrome
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [temp-dir]:  [39mCreating temp dir at C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\karma-28976911
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [launcher]:  [39mC:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\karma-28976911 --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate http://localhost:7357/?id=28976911
[16:16:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [watcher]:  [39mResolved files:
[16:16:42][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [karma]:  [39mA browser has connected on socket WNLvjHxwETp4In9uP7A6
[16:16:42][Step 2/5]  [32mINFO [IE 11.0.0 (Windows 7)]:  [39mConnected on socket WNLvjHxwETp4In9uP7A6 with id 43795558
[16:16:42][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [launcher]:  [39mIE (id 43795558) captured in 2.943 secs
[16:16:42][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [launcher]:  [39mKilled extra IE process 652
[16:16:42][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [launcher]:  [39mProcess IE exited with code 0
[16:16:42][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [temp-dir]:  [39mCleaning temp dir C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\karma-43795558
[16:16:59][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [karma]:  [39mA browser has connected on socket 4O99QMVW24pEsJBGP7A7
[16:16:59][Step 2/5]  [32mINFO [Firefox 32.0.0 (Windows 7)]:  [39mConnected on socket 4O99QMVW24pEsJBGP7A7 with id 44455821
[16:16:59][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [launcher]:  [39mFirefox (id 44455821) captured in 20.586 secs
[16:17:00][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [launcher]:  [39mProcess Firefox exited with code 0
[16:17:00][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [temp-dir]:  [39mCleaning temp dir C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\karma-44455821
[16:17:39][Step 2/5]  [33mWARN [launcher]:  [39mChrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
[16:17:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [launcher]:  [39mProcess Chrome exited with code 0
[16:17:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [temp-dir]:  [39mCleaning temp dir C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\karma-28976911
[16:17:39][Step 2/5]  [32mINFO [launcher]:  [39mTrying to start Chrome again (1/2).
[16:17:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [launcher]:  [39mRestarting Chrome
[16:17:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [temp-dir]:  [39mCreating temp dir at C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\karma-28976911
[16:17:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [launcher]:  [39mC:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\karma-28976911 --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate http://localhost:7357/?id=28976911
[16:18:39][Step 2/5]  [33mWARN [launcher]:  [39mChrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
[16:18:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [launcher]:  [39mProcess Chrome exited with code 0
[16:18:39][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [temp-dir]:  [39mCleaning temp dir C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\karma-28976911
[16:18:40][Step 2/5]  [32mINFO [launcher]:  [39mTrying to start Chrome again (2/2).
[16:18:40][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [launcher]:  [39mRestarting Chrome
[16:18:40][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [temp-dir]:  [39mCreating temp dir at C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\karma-28976911
[16:18:40][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [launcher]:  [39mC:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\karma-28976911 --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate http://localhost:7357/?id=28976911
[16:19:40][Step 2/5]  [33mWARN [launcher]:  [39mChrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
[16:19:40][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [launcher]:  [39mProcess Chrome exited with code 0
[16:19:40][Step 2/5]  [36mDEBUG [temp-dir]:  [39mCleaning temp dir C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\karma-28976911
[16:19:40][Step 2/5] Process exited with code 1
```

Comment: I'm seeing a similar problem on our build server, although we're using Hudson. Chrome has no problems launching when I try a local build, but it eventually fails on tests and source files that haven't been touched in over a year. The errors in a local build follow this pattern: `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property...`

None of this happens if I use Firefox instead of Chrome.

Comment: We recently saw this issue in team city as well.  We are going to try to verify on older version here: http://www.oldapps.com/google_chrome.php

Comment: We decided to go headless and switch to PhantomJS.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, but with Jenkins. It seemed to happen with the latest update of Chrome. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472457/jenkins-karma-chrome-not-working-after-last-auto-update-of-chrome

Comment: Yeah this is a chrome bug. [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=422218)

Comment: Don't work either with Jenkins, add to change for PhantomJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a chrome bug with the latest release of chrome. 
The problem seems to be with launching chrome from a service.
The chromium team has fixed the issue and it will be included with the next release which is expected around November 20, 2014

[issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=422218)