# karma + Chrome not working after last auto-update of Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jenkins, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

We use jenkins with a number of jenkins slave nodes running on Windows 7. Through jenkins we kick off karma tests to be run on the slave node to run our jasmine tests on the actual browsers. Suddenly last week after Chrome auto-updated to version "38.0.2125.104 m" this stopped working (karma unable to capture the browser). Here are our logs:

```
[INFO] --- maven-karma-plugin:1.8:start (default-cli) @ module-translation ---
[INFO] Executing Karma Test Suite ...
[INFO] cmd /C karma start C:\dev\util\jenkinsMaster\workspace\ci_module_translation_browser\translation\target\test-classes\frontend\thirdParty\js\com\verisk\underwriting\config\karma-config-module\1.0.3\karma-config-module-1.0.3.js --browsers Chrome --single-run
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.5 server started at http://localhost:9876/ 
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome 
WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing. 
INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2). 
WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing. 
INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2). 
WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing. 
ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up.
```

When running locally, the same command (using the karma-maven-plugin) works just fine. The karma plugin just runs the karma executable installed separately (which also works when run locally). Additionally, other browsers work when kicked off from jenkins. They have been working for quite some time now, along with Chrome (until this last update from Chrome). It is only the combination of the three: jenkins + karma + Chrome that is resulting in this issue.

Since Chrome has made it as hard as possible to get an older version, this has been very hard to test or resolve. Everything seems to be pointing to the current version of Chrome as the culprit.

Has anyone else seen this or have a solution?

Comment: Same issue here. Im using Chrome "38.0.2125.104 m" as well. After turn on the debug print, I can see the Chrome process was started with command `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-28077601 --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate http://localhost:9876/?id=28077601`. But the browser didn't actually started and not loading the page. Looking forward to a solution.

Comment: Yep.  Same behavior in our CI system ... we use TeamCity.

Comment: It's good to hear I'm in company. I've posted this as well: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/9m02Ke1PvJg

Comment: The issue to watch: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=422218

Comment: Same here, only on ci => teamcity.

Comment: Same problem here Mac OSX 10.6.8, Chrome 38.0.2125.104 and the following in phonecat/package.json: karma "~0.12", "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.4".  I had to use that karma version directive to get rid of an fsevents error.  The actual versions of the packages that were installed in phonecat/node_modules/ are:  karma => "version": "0.12.24"; karma-chrome-launcher => "version": "0.1.5".  The phonecat tutorial does not seem like like a very good advertisement for angularJS--the pros can't even get a simple tutorial to work for beginners.

Comment: I think that this thread can be useful: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=928

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix has been [merged into Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=422218#c70). The fix is now available through a regular update of Chrome. This works for version Chrome 39.0.2171.

Comment: I am using Version 48.0.2564.97 m (64-bit), but still getting this issue... It's irritating...